# How to draw a trajectory using opengl in a way that it appears to be dynamically drawn?

Tags: opengl, graphics, graphics2d, opengl-3

I have written a code for the trajectory of a projectile. Physics and basic code is not the problem. 
The only problem is that when i run this code I get to see the final path. Instead I want to see it being drawn in a step-by-step (point-by-point) fashion.

I cannot use sleep since it also only draws the final frame.

Help me out.

Here is the code

```
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<GL/gl.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define pi 3.141592654
#define g 10 
float x_0 =0 , y_0=0,x=0,y=0  ;
float theta = (pi)/3;
float v_0 = 30; //meters per second
float tof ;
float X[100],Y[100];
void calc(void)
{
int i;
tof = 2*v_0*sin(theta)/g;
  float del_t = tof/100;
  float temp=0;
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
  {
  x = v_0*cos(theta)*temp;
  y = v_0*sin(theta)*temp - ((g*temp*temp)/2);
  X[i]=x;
  Y[i]=y;
  temp += del_t;
  }
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  printf("%f %f\n",X[i],Y[i]);
}
void display(void)
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  //glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);

  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
  calc();
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<100;i++)
  glVertex2f(X[i],Y[i]);
  glEnd();
  glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
int i;


 glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
 glutInitWindowSize (800, 600);
 glutInitWindowPosition (0,0);

 glutCreateWindow ("Projectile Motion");
 glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 gluOrtho2D(0.0,500.0,0.0,400.0);
 glutDisplayFunc(display);
 glutMainLoop();

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int draw_endpoint = 0;
int n_points = 100; /* or however many points you have */

void idle(void)
{
  draw_endpoint = (draw_endpoint + 1) % n_points;
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display(void)
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  //glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);

  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
  for(int i=0;i<draw_endpoint;i++)
  glVertex2f(X[i],Y[i]);
  glEnd();
  glFlush();
}
```

and in main

```
 glutDisplayFunc(display);
 glutIdleFunc(idle);
 glutMainLoop();
```

Call calc only when the trajectory actually changes. Oh and by the way, on Earth `g = 9.81 m//s²`. While 10 is a nice approximation for ballpark estimations, for real animations the real value should be used (except of course, if you're simulating movements on a different celestial body).

Comment: Can i dare to ask for a little explanation...? 
P.S. BTW Thanks a lot. It works now.. :)

Comment: essentially it lets draw_endpoint vary from 0 to the total amount of points

Comment: @SidharthKamboj: I think it would be more instructive for you to try to understand what I did. If you explained it, you may read the explanation think "oh! I got it!" but there's a certain probability that you actually didn't get it. I'm not trying to be a dick here, but I sense that you're not yet accustomed to "think like a computer"; there are people who can do that naturally it seems, but others have to train it. I think you may fall into the second category. So I prescribe you a little exercise. Try to figure it out, that's the fun part :)

Comment: I have another question.
`void mouse(int button, int state , int x1,int y1)
{
float tmp = y1/x1;
if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
theta = atan(tmp);
}` 
In this code the x1 and y1 values are those of the screen pixel coordinates. How do i convert them to the frame coordinate? I am changing the throw angle upon clicking.

Comment: @SidharthKamboj: You have to unproject your window position (`gluUnProject` is your friend, though with modern OpenGL you probably want a non-GLU version). Remember that you only get 2 values, but you have so solve for a system of 3 independent variables (x, y and **z**). So what you get is not a point, but a ray into your scene. To do this you unproject the same x and y window coordinates but for different depth. This gives you 2 points between which the ray extends and beyond. You then have to intersect that ray with your scene.

Comment: Actually i altered the click position in the display window using suitable maths. Thanks anyway... :)